# jquery Ajax not saving to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a php file that has jquery ajax on it to submit a form and save its contents into a mysql without doing a page refresh.

My issue is if I load the file that the ajax call does the contents are saved into the database however if I try to use the form nothing gets saved to the database even though I get a success message.

Here is my code

The HTML file

```
    <div id='backinstock-form'>
          <form>
              <input id='instockemailadr'> 
              <input id='instockpid' value='5' type='hidden'> 
              <input name='submit' class='submitbackinstock' type='button' value='Submit'>
        </form>
        <span class='error' style='display:none'> Please Enter A Valid Email</span>
        <span class='success' style='display:none'> Email Submitted Success</span>
    </div>

    require(['jquery'], function($) 
    {
       $(".submitbackinstock").click(function() 
        {
            var instockemailadr = $("#instockemailadr").val();
            var instockpid = $("#instockpid").val();
            var dataString = 'usereaddr='+ instockemailadr + '&sku=' + instockpid;

            if(instockemailadr =='' || instockpid =='')
            {
                $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
             }
             else
             {
                 //console.log(dataString);
                 var dataString = new formData();
                 dataString.append('usereaddr', instockemailadr);
                 dataString.append('sku',instockpid);

                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>/pub/media/theme_customization/backin-stock-email-code/backinstock_process_email.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(){
                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    }
                });
            }
             return false;
            });
         });
```

The PHP File

```
<?php
   // MySQL portion
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");

   mysqli_select_db($conn,"multisitedb");
   $usereaddr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usereaddr']);
   $stockproductid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sku']);
   $created_on = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO multisitedb.backinstock_email_addresses(email_addr, product_sku, created_on) 
                          VALUES ('$usereaddr','$stockproductid','$created_on')");

     if($result) {
         echo $result; // or whatever you want
      } else {
         echo "Something went wrong.";
      }

  ?>
```

Comment: You didn't select a database.

Comment: Plus, this `"Something went wrong.";` will error out as a parse error.

Comment: You're open to sql injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: put an id to your form and write a onsubmit function to do ajax calls. also user serialize method to form and pass the data

Answer (score -1):

First, you didn't specify a Database in your php script. The format is `mysqli_connect(host, username, password, database)`;

Secondly, your ajax code seems wrong. You're making a post request. The data should be an instance of formData(). You can modify this way:

```
 var dataString = new formData();
dataString.append('usereaddr', instockemailadr);
dataString.append('sku',instockpid);
//...
 data: dataString,
 success: function(){
```

Also, your PHP script is not doing security checks. You need to validate user inputs as well as use prepared statements to prevent against SQL injection attack.

Comment: I updated my code above. Not sure if the way the $.ajax is written is correct since it still doesnt work?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Do you mean server returns no response? Or the response is "Something went wrong"?

Kindly open your dev tools (right click and select 'inspect' on chrome). Paste whichever error you see in the console tab here. If none, switch to the network tab, submit the form again and see what the server returns.

Comment: I mean there is no message seen in the browser and in the console the message says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier which is the line that says var dataString = new formData();

Comment: Move this part `var dataString = new formData();
            dataString.append('usereaddr', instockemailadr);
            dataString.append('sku',instockpid);` to before the `$.ajax({`

Comment: Thank you @Djunehor see my original post for updated code. I am getting an error that says Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined

Comment: Change `new formData();` to `new FormData();`. Notice the uppercase difference, It was a typo from my end.

Comment: so now i get a Uncaught TypeError: dataString.append is not a function

Comment: Have you deleted this line : `   var dataString = 'usereaddr='+ instockemailadr + '&sku=' + instockpid;`